# Return address/info in address for CountIfs function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have an Excel file with a large amount of COUNTIFS functions. The formulas work fine but I need to be able to find a way to return not only the address for each COUNTIFS, but also what is in the cell.

I created a simplified worksheet with what the data set looks like. My countifs function looks something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$3:A$7,"="&G3,B$3:B$7,">="&H3,C$3:C$7,"<="&I3)
```

I have looked at similar problems on here and tried two user defined functions:

```
Public Function ListAddresses(SearchTerm As Variant, SearchRange As Range) As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet, rCell As Range

    Set WS = Sheets(SearchRange.Parent.Name)
    SearchTerm = UCase(SearchTerm)

    Set SearchRange = Intersect(WS.UsedRange, SearchRange)

    For Each rCell In SearchRange.Cells
        If UCase(rCell.Value) = SearchTerm Then
            ListAddresses = ListAddresses & rCell.Address(False, False) & " | "
        End If

    Next rCell

    If ListAddresses <> "" Then
        ListAddresses = Left(ListAddresses, Len(ListAddresses) - 3)
    Else
        ListAddresses = "<none>"
    End If
```

and

```
Public Function CountIfFinder(rng As Range, crit As String) As String
    Dim r As Range, DQ As String

    DQ = Chr(34)
    crit = DQ & crit & DQ
    CountIfFinder = ""
    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

    For Each r In rng
        s = "=countif(" & r.Address & "," & crit & ")"
        If Evaluate(s) = 1 Then CountIfFinder = CountIfFinder & "," & r.Address(0, 0)
    Next r

    CountIfFinder = Mid(CountIfFinder, 2)
```

Any help would be appreciated because as of now I have to search through the DapSeq peaks by hand to find the peaks that match and there are almost 118,000 of them (yikes).

The question marks are the info from the addresses that I would need the function(s) to return.

[image: click for picture of problem]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What will be result in question marks if you put manually? What do you mean by peak as you shown same peak to multiple time?

Comment: If I understand the question, you are looking for "1:200" in L3 and 69 in L4.  What are you looking for row 6 where there are two matches?  Another set of coordinates and strengths off to the right?

Comment: @Harun24HR The question marks just serve as a placeholder for what I need the function to return. In the technique of Dap-Seq there are many peaks, not only one. So I am searching to find peaks that occur within the range of the gene. There can be many peaks that occur within that range so the function needs to be able to return many coordinates for each gene. The peak column on the right shows how many peaks were found within the gene shown to the left.

Comment: @Axuary Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. When there are 2 peaks that occur within that range I would like the function to show the coordinates of all the peaks found (whether it be 1,2,3,4 etc.) So yeah showing the second set to the right would work.